# Command Pattern with additional argument parsing

Tags: java, parsing, design-patterns, structure

Recently I have really focused on design patterns and implementing them to solve different problems. Today I am working on the Command Pattern.

I have ended up creating an interface:

```
public interface Command {
    public void execute();
}
```

I have several concrete implementations:

```
public class PullCommand implements Command {

    public void execute() {
        // logic
    }
}
```

and:

```
public class PushCommand implements Command {

    public void execute() {
        // logic
    }
}
```

There are several other commands as well.

Now.. the thing is there's a `BlockingQueue<Command>` which runs on a different thread using `.take()` to retrieve queued commands and execute them as they come in (I'd call this **Executor** class below) by another class which produces them by parsing the user input and using `.queue()`. So far so good...

The hard part about me is parsing the command (CLI application).
I have put all of them in a HashMap:

```
private HashMap<String, Command> commands = new HashMap<String, Command>();
commands.put("pull", new PullCommand());
commands.put("push", new PushCommand());
//etc..
```

When user inputs a command, the syntax is such that one thing is for sure, and it is that the "action" (pull / push) comes as first argument, so I can always do `commands.get(arguments[0])` and check if that is null, if it is, then the command is invalid, if it isn't, then I have successfully retrieved an object that represents that command. The tricky part is that there are other arguments that also need to be parsed and for each command the algorithm for parsing it, is different... Obviously one thing I can do is put the `arguments[]` as a parameter to the method `execute()` and end up having `execute(String[] args)` but that would mean I have to put the parsing of arguments inside the `execute()` method of the command, which I would like to avoid for several reasons:

1. The execution of Command happens on a different thread that uses a `BlockingQueue`, it executes a single command, then another one etc.. The logic I would like to put inside `execute()` has to ONLY be the execution of the command itself, without the parsing or any for example heavy tasks which would slow the execution (I do realize parsing several args would not mess up the performance that much.. but here I am learning structural designs and ways to build good coding habits and nice solutions. This would not be perfect by any mean)
2. It makes me feel like I am breaking some fundamental principles of the "Command" pattern. (Even if not so, I'd like to think of a better way to solve this)

It is obvious that I cannot use the constructor of the concrete commands since `HashMap` returns already initialized objects. Next thing that comes to mind is using another method inside the object that "processes" (`process(String[] args)`) the arguments and sets private variables to the result of the parsing and this `process(String[] args)` method is called by the **Producer** class before doing `queue()` on the command, so the parsing would end up OUT of the **Executor** class (thread) and **Point 1.** from above would not be a problem.

But there's another problem.. What happens if a user enters a lot of commands to the application, the application does `.get(args[0])` on the arguments and retrieves a `PullCommand`, it uses the `process(String[] args)` and private variables are set, so the command is **queued** to the **Executor** class and it is **waiting** to be executed. Meanwhile.. another command is input by the user, `.get(args[0])` is used again, it retrieves a `PullCommand` from the `HashMap` (but that `PullCommand` is the same as the one that is queued for execution) and `process()` would be called **BEFORE** the command has been executed by the **Executor** class and it would screw up the private variables. We would end up with 2 PullCommands records in the BlockingQueue, second one would be correct from user point of view (since he input what he wants it to do and it does just that), but first one will be the same as the second one (since it is the same object) and it would not correspond to the initial arguments.

Another thing I thought of is using a **Factory** class that implements the parsing for each of the commands and returns the appropriate Command object.
This would mean though, that I need to change the way `HashMap` is used and instead of Command I have to use the Factory class instead:

```
HashMap<String, CommandFactory> commands = new HashMap<String, CommandFactory>();
commands.put("pull", new CommandFactory("pull"));
commands.put("pull", new CommandFactory("push"));
```

and based on the String passed to the Factory, its `process()` method would use the appropriate parsing for that command and it would return the corresponding Command object, but this would mean that this class could potentially be very big because of containing the parsing for all commands..

Overall, this seems like my only option, but I am very hesitant since from structural point of view, I don't think I am solving this problem nicely. Is this a nice way to deal with this situation? Is there anything I am missing? Is there any way I can maybe refactor part of my code to ease it?

Comment: sorry it's too long to read so i stopped in the middle. let me summarize, your question is basically if you can separate the logic of command line parsing from the `Command` interface, is it? well, then you can use builder pattern can't you?(you mentioned factory at the end but technically speaking it should be builder pattern).

Comment: when checking if a command is invalid, simply do commands.containsKey(arguments[0]), then if true, you should execute the command. Use the built in hashmap methods. No reason to call get() if your map doesn't contain that key. Thats why there exists a containsKey method in the first place

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr Yes, sumarized it could be said that way.. I am looking for the nicest structural solution in this situation. I haven't thought of Builder pattern and I feel totally amazed how I could have missed that. It sounds like a nice option.

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz I have no problem with this whatsoever so this comes to no help at all, here I am talking about structural solution for the bigger picture. I have no problem with the HashMap.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr When implementing the Builder pattern, I'd have to do it for each command - PullCommand, PushCommand etc.. but the HashMap contains a Command (interface), the builder won't be visible when retrieving from the HashMap. And trying to implement the Builder pattern inside the interface to fix this seems wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are over thinking this. The command pattern is basically "keep everything you need to know how do something and do it later", so it's OK to pass stuff to the execution code.

Just do this:

- user inputs a `String[]`
- first string is the command "name" (use it as you are now)
- the remaining strings are the parameters to the command (if any)
- change your interface to `public void execute(String[] parameters);`
- to execute, pass the parameters to the command object

Comment: So I'd also have to change the way I queue() the command to the Executor class which contains a BlockingQueue, and calls execute(), but has no hold of the arguments, I'd have to refactor this just slightly.

Comment: @Hubbs not exactly. Create a wrapper class that has fields for a Command and a String[], then queue those. At execution time, pass the String[] to the Command.

Answer (score 0):

Throwing a design question broadly like this in SO is in general not a good idea. It's a bit surprising to only see a downvote with no close request.

In any case, without understanding your problem thoroughly, it's hard to say what's the "best" design, not to mention if it I did, I won't call anything to be the best. Therefore I will stick with what I say by using Builder pattern.

In general, a builder pattern is used whenever the logic of construction is too complicated to fit in constructor, or it's necessarily divided into phases. In this case, if you want some extreme diversity of how your commands should look like depending on action, then you will want some builder like this:

```
interface CommandBuilder<T extends Command> {
    void parseArgs(String[] args);
    T build();
}
```

Generic here is optional if you don't plan to use these builders more than your current architecture, otherwise it's beneficial to be more precise in the types. `parseArgs` is responsible for those necessary parsing you were referring to. `build` should spit out an instance of `Command` depending on your current arguments.

Then you want your dispatcher map to look like this:

```
HashMap<String, Supplier<? extends CommandBuilder<? extends Command>>> builders = new HashMap<>();
commands.put("pull", () -> new PullBuilder());
commands.put("push", () -> new PushBuilder());
// etc
```

Any of these builders can potentially have extremely complicated logic, as you would desire. Then you can do

```
CommandBuilder builder = builders.get(args[0]).get();
builder.setArgs(args);
queue.add(builder.build());
```

In this way, your `Command` interface can focus on what exact it's supposed to do.

Notice that after your `builders` map is built, everything goes statically, and mutation is localized. I don't fully understand what's your concern, but it should be addressed by doing this.

However, it could be an overkill design, depending on what you want to do.